# Program a PIC24FJ64GB002 with a pickit 2

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programmer

I am trying to program a PIC24FJ64GB002 with a pickit 2 but when I try to program it, the pickit 2 application says that no device was found, despite the chip being hooked up with the programmer. So far the pickit 2 has worked programming any other chip, so I don't see why this one is different.  Do different settings need to be activated in the pickit 2 application?  I am using a pickit 2 clone but I don't think it is the problem because it works with several other types of pics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the PIC24FJ64GB002 to be programmed by the pickit2, a capacitor needs to be placed between VCAP and ground for the programmer to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

PICkit 2 does not support the PIC24FJ64GB002, either as a programmer or as a debugger. See below from MPLAB

[image]

Comment: But the micro is listed on the compatibility list http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkit%202%20Readme%20v2-61-00%20(a).txt

Comment: Select Pickit 2 Programmer menu 'help/about' - what device file and firmware version does it report?  Calibrate Vdd ('Tools' menu). Enable 'Manual device select' ('Programmer' menu), and select  PIC24FJ64GB002. What happens when you try to read the PIC?